# Como posicionar uma tag Span na página?

Tags: css, html5, asp.net-mvc-5, posicionamento

Estou estudando ASP.NET MVC 5 e estou tentando criar uma página onde, no canto superior esquerdo, eu teria um botão "Menu", consegui criar o botão e ação, porém estou com dificuldades para localizar o botão na pagina.

Eu quero que esse botão fique no topo esquerdo da página e não desça por mais que o texto seja grande, porém do jeito que estou fazendo, conforme o texto cresce o botão desce.

Código HTML:

```
    @model WebApplication3.Models.MenuInicialModels

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Inicial";
}

<h1>TESTE 1</h1>
<h2>TESTE</h2>
<h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sapien sem, viverra sed semper non, elementum ut mi. Nullam quis rutrum nisl, non pharetra magna. Ut fringilla sollicitudin aliquam. Maecenas et felis non nibh consequat lobortis. Phasellus ornare sagittis tortor a dapibus. Pellentesque eget sapien condimentum, suscipit orci et, mollis lacus. Donec sit amet sodales arcu. Sed est urna, imperdiet ac sollicitudin at, posuere quis nibh. Integer sollicitudin gravida velit, non dapibus tortor accumsan eget. Praesent vitae eleifend nibh. Vivamus mollis sit amet tellus eu ultrices. Fusce in libero egestas, bibendum neque nec, porta dui. Sed sagittis posuere massa eget vulputate. Donec ipsum eros, congue et ante sit amet, finibus faucibus velit. Donec rhoncus vel mauris venenatis feugiat.

Duis metus enim, interdum vel nunc varius, iaculis placerat metus. Aliquam sagittis consequat magna, eu volutpat ipsum efficitur non. Nulla tincidunt vehicula metus, sed dignissim ligula tincidunt vel. Sed vitae nibh ac quam pellentesque varius in et neque. Vestibulum lobortis venenatis rhoncus. Integer maximus porttitor volutpat. Duis arcu orci, ultricies ut ullamcorper at, vulputate sit amet sem. Vivamus nec libero nec risus condimentum fringilla. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed ultricies dui et orci sagittis, quis maximus est gravida. Praesent quis sollicitudin nunc. Sed eu nunc aliquet, vulputate justo vel, iaculis sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut consectetur neque ac ante porta congue.</h4>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="Open_menu">
    <span onclick="openNav()">Menu</span>
</div>
```

Código CSS:

```
    .sidenav {
    height: 100%; /* 100% Full-height */
    width: 0; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111; /* Black*/
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    padding-top: 60px; /* Place content 60px from the top */
    transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
}

/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}

/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

/* Style page content - use this if you want to push the page content to the right when you open the side navigation */
#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 20px;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
    .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}

#Open_menu {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-left: -120px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Página:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Utilizando a tag `position: fixed` o botão, ficou na posição fixa ao rolar a pagina, porém ao ser adcionado um texto maior, o botão desceu:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Parece que ele esta "linkado" com o footer, pois se altero o valor da tag `margin-top:` o footer tambem acompanha a modificação.

Comment: Coloca a estrutura html da página...

Comment: Você quer que esse botão fiquei flutuante? Ou obedeça o container? Não entendi muito bem onde ele deveria ficar

Comment: quero que ele fique parado, no canto superior esquerdo, abaixo da barra azul

Comment: Da forma como vc editou a regra só ocorre na mediaquerie, se for usar essa 1º solução tem de colocar fora da media...

Comment: "Como posicionar uma tag Span na página?" é uma dúvida muito vaga, e não permite uma solução clara que ajude outras pessoas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bom de qual quer forma, você pode usar (como uma das opções) o `position:fixed`.

```
#Open_menu {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    margin-top : 70px;
    margin-left: 33px;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size: 20px;            
}
```

Ou pode mudar para :

```
    @model WebApplication3.Models.MenuInicialModels

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Inicial";
}
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
<div id="Open_menu">
    <span onclick="openNav()">Menu</span>
</div>
<h1>TESTE 1</h1>
<h2>TESTE</h2>
<h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sapien sem, viverra sed semper non, elementum ut mi. Nullam quis rutrum nisl, non pharetra magna. Ut fringilla sollicitudin aliquam. Maecenas et felis non nibh consequat lobortis. Phasellus ornare sagittis tortor a dapibus. Pellentesque eget sapien condimentum, suscipit orci et, mollis lacus. Donec sit amet sodales arcu. Sed est urna, imperdiet ac sollicitudin at, posuere quis nibh. Integer sollicitudin gravida velit, non dapibus tortor accumsan eget. Praesent vitae eleifend nibh. Vivamus mollis sit amet tellus eu ultrices. Fusce in libero egestas, bibendum neque nec, porta dui. Sed sagittis posuere massa eget vulputate. Donec ipsum eros, congue et ante sit amet, finibus faucibus velit. Donec rhoncus vel mauris venenatis feugiat.

Duis metus enim, interdum vel nunc varius, iaculis placerat metus. Aliquam sagittis consequat magna, eu volutpat ipsum efficitur non. Nulla tincidunt vehicula metus, sed dignissim ligula tincidunt vel. Sed vitae nibh ac quam pellentesque varius in et neque. Vestibulum lobortis venenatis rhoncus. Integer maximus porttitor volutpat. Duis arcu orci, ultricies ut ullamcorper at, vulputate sit amet sem. Vivamus nec libero nec risus condimentum fringilla. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed ultricies dui et orci sagittis, quis maximus est gravida. Praesent quis sollicitudin nunc. Sed eu nunc aliquet, vulputate justo vel, iaculis sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut consectetur neque ac ante porta congue.</h4>
```

E no css

```
#Open_menu {
    float: left;
    margin-top : 70px;
    margin-left: 33px;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size: 20px;            
}
```

Comment: Amigo, para que serve esse `z=index: 999`

Comment: Ele vai dizer em para o elemento de posicionar na primeira camada, o correto é `z-index`, e coloquei o valor `999`pois não sabia se tinha outros elementos com `position fixed` também, se não tiver o valor pode ser `1`.

Comment: amigo, utilizando o seu código, ele fica com a posição fixa, ok, porém quando eu adiciono o texto, ele continua descendo, fiz uma revisão na pergunta

Comment: Ah, então o local aonde eu coloco minha div no html, influencia o posicionamento?

Comment: Opa... Por isso pedi para colocar a estrutura toda, no documento todo mundo anda de mão dada ... Caso alguma das respostas estiver correta, poderia validá-la, clicando no icon verde abaixo das setas de avaliação da resposta escolhida....@ThomasErichPimentel espero ter ajudado...

Comment: Perfeito. não sabia obrigado